# Renaming child-theme folder fixed wp-admin blank

Tags: wp-admin, child-theme

Weird thing happened. I have a WP instance, and I wanted to have a local copy.

I copied all the files, created the DB from a dump, and everything seemed to be working fine. However, when going to `wp-admin`, BLANK SCREEN.

I renamed the child-theme from `alterna-child` to `alterna-child2` and then I could login. I deactivated the alterna-child theme, and then activate it back, but if I logout, I can't access the admin either.

I am confused, because in the live site this is not happening.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I have tried removing all the files from the theme, and I can see that the file that creates the conflicts is functions.php, which contains the following:

```
include(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/graduates_functions.php');
```

And yes, I have `graduates_functions.php`

Comment: [Enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and check for errors.

Comment: Check if `WP_CONTENT_DIR` really points to the correct location.